# What kind of parallelism is Proverbs 18:22 and how is it translated?

Tags: hebrew, proverbs, syntax

There are different kinds of parallelism in the book of Proverbs and I would like to know which one is in Proverbs 18:22 and how it is translated in terms of its original audience and present significance.

Proverbs 18:22 NIV

> He who finds a wife finds what is good and receives favor from the LORD.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX. Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

Prov 18:22 consists of just seven Hebrew words and literally translates as follows:

> finds wife finds good & obtains favor from YHWH

Thus, the BSB & ESV (most other are similar) translates the implied "extra" words to make an idiomatic English version:

> He who finds a wife finds a good thing and obtains favor from the
> LORD.

Apart from the first two pairs of words, there is little parallelism here unless one sets it out thus:

> finds wife
>
> finds good
>
> & obtains favor from Jehovah

Set out thus, Prov 18:22 quintessential Hebrew synthetic parallelism.  However, one might more helpfully simply call this an aphorism or maxim, similar in scope to one of the common English maxims, eg, "Happy wife, happy life."  That is, a classic proverb.

Indeed, most of the proverbs in Prov 18 are of this extremely terse form where "parallelism" is questionable.  However, there are many other longer "proverbs" elsewhere in Proverbs that are written in unquestionably parallel style, here is one of them:

Proverbs 24:5, 6 -

> A wise man is strong,
>
> and a man of knowledge enhances his strength.
>
> Only with sound guidance should you wage war,
>
> and victory lies in a multitude of counselors.

Comment: Who are the original recipients for whom the author intended the message   .. Can we say any person who finds a wife or is it strictly limited to Israelites?

Comment: @user60313 - the original proverb was written for the Hebrews.  However, we are all aware that some marriages are unhappy and that some people should never marry.  That is the subject of another question.  This proverb is clearly intended for the "ideal" marriage.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up these verses.

findeth a wife

Prov 5:15-23; Prov 12:4; Prov 19:14; Prov 31:10-31; Gen 24:67; Gen 29:20; Gen 29:21; Gen 29:28; Eccl 9:9 Hos 12:12; 1Cor 7:2

and

Prov 3:4; Prov 8:35

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).